# The use of "consigne" and "que" in this sentence

Tags: vocabulaire

I came about the following sentence:

“Consigne: Avec votre dictionnaire, trouvez deux mots de la même famille que”

I understood that with my dictionary I have to find two words with the same family. What do “consigne” and “que” mean here?

Comment: The sentence is incomplete, "que" has to be followed by the word / words. It's [même](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%C3%AAme#Adjective) que you have to look for. And [consigne](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consigne#Noun_2) is also in the wiktionary.

Comment: Try and look in different dictionaries. *Consigne* must be be in any dictionary, and if you can find même in a dictionary you're bound to have an example sentence with *que*. For instance [here](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/m%C3%AAme%20que)  or [here](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/la+m%EAme+famille+que.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Consigne" means "instruction". Here, it just announces that the following sentence is the thing to be done. Similarly you could find in an exercise book:

> Exercise: What is 2+2 worth?

The final "que" is a part of the expression "la même que", in this context "the same family as". As Laure said, it seems there is a word missing.

Your interpretation would be good if the que was not here.

"de la même famille": "from the same family"

"de la même famille que x": from the same family as x".